# How do I get the PrinterIndex using the Printer Name using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, printing, printers

I need to assign a printer for each of three different printing functions, labels, receipts and "standard" (e.g. A4).  I have identified all of the printers available using `listbox1.assign(printer.printers)` but there doesn't appear to be a way to use this to establish the printer's  `PrinterIndex`.  I want to store the printername and index value in a file so that I can use `printer.printerindex` to assign a printer to each type of print job without asking the user to choose a printer using a dialog.

Am I going about this the wrong way, and if so, could someone please tell me the right way to do it, please?   I've not had to use the `printers` unit directly before.

Comment: Storing printer index is not a good idea because the index may change if the user add/remove/reinstall printers.

Comment: I think I can control that since no one except me would add/delete a printer driver.   Is it possible to use the printer name directly?

Comment: You'll probably find an good answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277061/print-to-a-non-default-printer-in-delphi

Comment: Thanks fpiette.  I'll certainly try that, without the ```vcl```!

Comment: It has also occurred to me that I can check the index each time using the printer name.  This works, so thanks very much.   Will happily accept your answer if you care to set one up.

Comment: That was the link that fpiette sent me above.   I had seen it, but ignored it because it didn't seem to be the problem I was trying to resolve.   However, I was wrong!   It was exactly what I needed.    Thanks for sending it, though.

Comment: Interesting, I just marked the q as a duplicate. SO then must have done an automatic comment!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print to a non default printer in delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277061/print-to-a-non-default-printer-in-delphi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the printer name in the file, not the index.

When you restart the program and read back the printer name. Then loop thru all printers to find which one has the saved name (It could have been removed or renamed) and use that printer.

Comment: No need to loop through, just use ``Printer.printers.IndexOf``.

Comment: In the case of Windows Terminal Server, the session number must be removed from the printer name! In this case the loop is required.